# Problems with loops and integers in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

I've been teaching myself javascript for the past week or so and I've been stuck for the past couple days on loops.

I have a list of 15 items on a page, 15 text boxes to exact and I wish to copy them from one side of the screen to the other with a loop and 15  tags.

```
var variablenamer = "reitem"; 
var number = i; 
var stringholder = variablenamer.concat(number);
document.getElementById(stringholder).innerHTML = "test"
```

This code works outside of a loop,(provided I set i to 1).

so I try to make it a loop like so:

```
for (i = 1, i < 16, i++){
    var variablenamer = "reitem";
    var number = i;
    var stringholder = variablenamer.concat(number);
    document.getElementById(stringholder).innerHTML = "test";
}
```

and all of the code on my page stops working. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

-Fred

Comment: double check the line `var number=i var`

Comment: You seem to miss a few semicolons `;`. Make sure to end every command with a semicolon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var i;
for (i=1;i<16;i++){
    var variablenamer = "reitem";
    var number = i;
    var stringholder = variablenamer.concat(number);
    document.getElementById(stringholder).innerHTML = "test";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

its semicolon

```
for (var i=1 ; i<16 ; i++){

}
```